# Check if an URL belongs to a resource within the same document domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I'm developing a script that checks every link (URL) in a Presentations to meet the following criteria:

- If the link follows to a document within the same domain of the Presentation that I'm currently editing then remove the link.

The question is, is there a property, or any method in GAPPS that allows me to check that information, because I've reviewed the whole API and I cannot find anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to get the domain that a file belongs to buy you might be able to get the Presentation owner by using [getOwner](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getowner) ( a method of the Class File from the Drive Service) or the equivalent of the Drive Advanced Service.

Once you get the owner email address, then you could extract the domain by using JavaScript's global object methods like `String.prototype.split`, regular expressions, etc.

Related

- [Determine the owner of a Google Drive document with a service account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35046011/1595451)
- [returning document owner for large list of Google Drive doc IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38000942/1595451)

Comment: many thanks @rubén, I was able to get the domain using your approach, with the following fuctions `DriveApp.getFileById(resource_id).getOwner().getDomain()`, also, I extracted the id from the resource using this regex `/google\.com\/\w+\/d\/(\S+)\/\w+/`, in case someone else needs it.